# Extending Clojure core protocols

Tags: clojure

*Warning: I'm almost certain I'm using at least some of the relevant terms wrong*

I want to modify [flatland.ordered.set.OrderedSet](https://github.com/amalloy/ordered#sets) so that `nth` works. I *think* this involves something like:

```
(extend-type flatland.ordered.set.OrderedSet
    ?????
    (nth [this n] (nth (vec this) n))
```

I've been trying to discern what protocol defines `nth` for a few hours now, with no luck. Is there a list of "native" protocols? Am I just totally mixed up?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible to do what you want to do using `extend-type`.  Clojure's persistent collection interfaces are implemented using Java interfaces, not Clojure protocols.  Therefore, it is not possible to extend them using `extend-type`.

However, since the [code](https://github.com/amalloy/ordered) is open source, you could always change the library itself.  All you should need to do is implement `nth` in `OrderedSet`'s `deftype`.  `nth` is defined by the [`clojure.lang.Indexed`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.clojure/clojure/1.6.0/clojure/lang/Indexed.java) interface.

Answer (score 3):

As [Nathan Davis says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728563/440294), you can't do this "from the outside", because this stuff is based on interfaces rather than protocols. It would be quite reasonable for OrderedSet to implement Indexed; I must have just overlooked that interface entirely.

On the other hand, your implementation of nth is very inefficient: you don't want to create an entire length-N vector just to look up a single element in it. Instead, you want to call into `get`, which does the same thing as `nth`.

---

**Edit**: having looked back over the code again, I see that `nth` is not nearly as easy to implement correctly, because the existence of disj makes it difficult to quickly tell how many elements have been dropped from the set where. I don't think an efficient implementation for `nth` can really exist for this data structure unless you remove the ability to use `disj`. So I probably won't accept a pull request implementing `nth` unless you figure out something really clever, but feel free to fork `ordered` and add it to your own fork if you don't need `disj` support.